# How do i set a predefined key before local-storage is set?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, game-development

I have a hotkey which clicks an element on the page and uses the default key 'r'. I also have an input which allows the hotkey to be changed when a key is inputted. When a value is inputted it is cached to local-storage. The only issue is the default key doesn't work with the event, only when the input is set to a value.

```
let IsInputing = true
let key = 82
 setTimeout(() => {
   key = localStorage.getItem('savedKey');

    input.onchange = function(){
        localStorage.setItem('savedKey', key)
    }

    window.addEventListener("keydown", activate, false);
    function activate(key) {
        if (IsInputing == false) {
            if (key.keyCode == key) {
                console.log('key pressed')
                element.click();
            }
        }
    }
    input.onkeydown = function (key) {
        IsInputing = true
        key = key.keyCode;
        console.log('key changed')
        setTimeout(changeKey, 1000)
    }
    function changeKey() {
        IsInputing = false;
    }
}, 500);
```

Comment: It looks like you may have a scoping issue with your `key` variables.

Comment: What do `{ }` mean around your code?

Comment: i tested without localstorage, the global key by default works

Comment: `key.keyCode == key` will probably not work as you intended no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that, the first time the code runs, you set `key` to `82`, and then you set it to whatever `localStorage.getItem` returns, which will return `null` if nothing is cached (first time).

```
let key = 82;

setTimeout(() => {
  key = localStorage.getItem('savedKey');
});
```

This means that your code essentially does:

```
key = 82;

setTimeout(() => {
  key = null; // <-- you overwrite the key with null on the first run
});
```

Try setting the default value for `key` only if `localStorage` doesn't have a previously cached value:

```
let DEFAULT_KEY = 82;
setTimeout(() => {
  key = localStorage.getItem('savedKey') || DEFAULT_KEY;
});
```

Or more tersely:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  key = localStorage.getItem('savedKey') || 82;
});
```

---

Note: to avoid some potential future bugs, you might want to convert your cached value to a number when you return it (`localStorage` only saves strings).

```
key = Number(localStorage.getItem('savedKey'));
```

Or use a string as your default value.

```
let DEFAULT_KEY = '82';

setTimeout(() => {
  key = localStorage.getItem('savedKey') || DEFAULT_KEY;
});
```

Having consistent types would avoid errors such as unexpected comparisons:

```js
'82' == 82  // true
'82' === 82 // false
```

---

As mentioned in the comments to my answer, you have another bug in the `activate` function.

You are naming the parameter of `activate` as `key`, which will shadow the global `key` variable when you do the `key.keyCode == key` comparison.

```
function activate(key) {
//                ^^^ you are using the same name as the global key
  if (IsInputing == false) {
    if (key.keyCode == key) {
       console.log('key pressed')
       element.click();
    }
  }
}
```

If `key` within `activate` was for example `'abcd'`, you code will do `'abcd'.keyCode == 'abcd'`.

One way to solve it is to rename the `activate`'s parameter:

```
function activate(activationKey) {
  if (IsInputing == false) {
    if (activationKey.keyCode == key) {
       console.log('key pressed')
       element.click();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help :). Happy JavaScripting!

Comment: Just a few notes: Storage.getItem returns `null` when no associated value is found, and there are more in OP's code that goes wrong, check for instance `key.keyCode == key`

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for the comment, fixed the `null` mistake. The `key.keyCode == key` will actually work in OP's code because `'82' == 82` (but yes, I did notice the potential bugs coming from type mismatch, hence my last note).

Comment: Just noticed that you meant variable shadowing, oops

Comment: No, read that line again. If `key` were the string `"82"`, or even the Number `82`, then its `.keyCode` property would be `undefined`.

Comment: @Kaiido yup, added that to my answer too.